# What if I have exception during subscription?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex, subscriber

I am trying to wrap "third party" publisher into RxJava. During subscribe, I am preparing publisher and this may cause exception (when publisher is not available).

What should I do with an exception?

1) Throw it from subscribe method?

2) Push it into observers' `OnError` method?

3) Something else?

I am thinking about pushing to `OnError`, then how to implement subscription? If `OnError` should be the last event in subscription, should I regard as subscription happen or not? What to return as `Subscription`? Just `NOP` lambda?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "publisher" and "wrap".

For example, there is an API call that returns `Observable` but the call itself may throw an unchecked exception. An easy way is to use `defer` that will catch that exception and relay it to the subscriber:

```
Observable.defer(() -> api.unreliableMethod())...
```

If you mean you have a Reactive-Streams `Publisher` and RxJava 2, you can simply call `Flowable.fromPublisher` or, again, `Flowable.defer(() -> publisher)` like above.

Otherwise, the [RxJavaReactiveStreams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams) let's you convert a `Publisher` into an `Observable` (and defer() the process to catch exceptions if needed):

```
Observable.defer(() ->
    RxJavaReactiveStreams.toObservable(api.unreliablePublisher()))...
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking about pushing to OnError, then how to implement subscription? If OnError should be the last event in subscription, should I regard as subscription happen or not? What to return as Subscription? Just NOP lambda?

This is actually how RxJava itself usually handles exceptions in the 'constructor' of each operator.

If you are working with RxJava2 then there is one additional rule you need to keep in mind. And that is that `Subscriber.onSubcribe()` must ALWAYS be called before `onError` and `onComplete`, so even if it immediately throws an exceptions, both `onSubscribe` and `onError` must be called.